# Plucker relations in orthogonal Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $G=SO_7$ and let $P$ be the maximal parabolic corresponding to the fundamental weight $\varpi_3$. Since $\varpi_3$ is minuscule, $G/P$ may be fairly easy to study. Is the structure of $G/P$ known in literature ? What are the Plücker type relations (quadratic) in this case ? Are the relations same as they are in the Grassmannian $G(3,7)$ ? I have a feeling that the quotient is $\mathbb P^2$.

Answer (score 12):

If $G = SO(7)$ and $P$ corresponds to $\varpi_3$, then
$$
G/P \cong Q^6
$$
is a 6-dimensional quadric. In particular, there is a unique Plücker relation in this case (the equation of the quadric).

The isomorphism can be sen as a combination of a general isomorphism
$$
SO(2n-1)/P_{\varpi_{n-1}} \cong SO(2n)/P_{\varpi_{n}} 
$$
and the triality isomorphism 
$$
SO(8)/P_{\varpi_{4}} \cong SO(8)/P_{\varpi_{1}} \cong Q^6.
$$

Comment: Ah, good point about triality!

Comment: Is there a reference why $SO(8)/P_{\varpi_1} \cong Q^6$ ?

Answer (score 7):

Standard Monomial Theory (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_monomial_theory) provides a uniform description of the coordinate ring of any minuscule $G/P$ (and in fact with more work applies to other $G/P$ as well). In the minuscule case the main result, due to Seshadri, is that a basis of the coordinate ring is given by multichains in the corresponding *minuscule poset*. However, this result only says that in principle there is some way to express a product of standard monomials as a sum of standard monomials (in other words, we have an "algebra with a straightening law"). But we might not know the explicit coefficients in this expression.

Fortunately, for the case you care about (the maximal orthogonal Grassmannian) the specific relations actually *have* been worked out. Namely, the paper "Pfaffians and Shuffling Relations for the Spin Module" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.2943) by Chirivì and Maffei contains the exact relations (phrased in terms of pfaffians of skew-symmetric matrices) you're looking for.

There is one small complication in that Chirivì and Maffei work with $So(2n+2)$ (Type D) and you're interested in $So(2n+1)$ (Type B), but if I remember correctly we actually have an isomorphism of the relevant varieties $OG(n+1,2n+2)\simeq OG(n,2n+1)$, so this makes no difference.

Comment: Does this mean that in this particular case the Plucker relation is same as those in $G(3,7)$ ? This is sitting inside $G(3,7)$ as a family of isotropic $3$ dimensional subspaces.

Comment: @icmesimrf: see my edited answer for a paper with the exact relations you're looking for.